# error of cannot compare a dtyped [datetime64[ns]] array with a scalar of type [bool] when using dataframe.loc

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

There is a dataframe, which has the following columns along with other columns

```
Identification                     time                       
368                              2006-1-18
440                              2007-1-30
452                              2006-12-20
464                              2007-1-18
```

At first, I transform the `time` column into related `datetime` type, using `df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])`

I would like select the certain rows, and use

```
 df.loc[df.time<='2017-1-29' & df.date>='2016-12-28' ]
```

But I got the following error message, what did I wrong?

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py in na_op(x, y)
   1273         try:
-> 1274             result = op(x, y)
   1275         except TypeError:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py in rand_(left, right)
    145 def rand_(left, right):
--> 146     return operator.and_(right, left)
    147 

TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_and' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py in na_op(x, y)
   1290                 try:
-> 1291                     result = libops.scalar_binop(x, y, op)
   1292                 except:

pandas\_libs\ops.pyx in pandas._libs.ops.scalar_binop()

ValueError: cannot include dtype 'M' in a buffer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-315be32eacf7> in <module>()
----> 1 df.loc[df.time<='2017-1-29' & df.time>='2016-12-28' ]

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py in wrapper(self, other)
   1328                       is_integer_dtype(np.asarray(other)) else fill_bool)
   1329 
-> 1330             res_values = na_op(self.values, other)
   1331             unfilled = self._constructor(res_values, index=self.index)
   1332             return filler(unfilled).__finalize__(self)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py in na_op(x, y)
   1294                                     "with a scalar of type [{typ}]"
   1295                                     .format(dtype=x.dtype,
-> 1296                                             typ=type(y).__name__))
   1297 
   1298         return result

TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped [datetime64[ns]] array with a scalar of type [bool]
```

Comment: `df.loc[(df.time<='2017-1-29') & (df.time>='2016-12-28') ]` will be useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's operator precedence. Bitwise operators are overloaded in pandas, but retain their precedence when parsed by the AST. You'll have to wrap the conditions in parens.

```
df.loc[(df.time <= '2017-1-29') & (df.time >= '2016-12-28')]
```

Also take a look at `pd.Series.between`, that works for both-sides-inclusive, or both-sides-exclusive range checks:

```
df.time.between('2016-12-28', '2017-1-29')
```